# math.random() follows which algorithms

Tags: java, random

Am using `math.random()` method to generate random numbers. but i had a doubt about that method. math.random() is which algorithms will fallow to generate random numbers. Is there any another random number generated algorithm?

Am trying this code but i think this is not efficient to generate random code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     int sd = i + (int) (Math.random() * (N-i));

     String t = one[r];
     one[r] = one[i];
     one[i] = t;
 }
```

Is there any better algorithm for random number generation?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what your algorithm is supposed to do?

Comment: @JBNizet Collections.shuffle for a String[] I guess...

Comment: What do you mean by efficient (fast, closer to real randomness, ...) ?

Answer (score 11):

Java mainly provides four random number generator API's depending of your use case.

### java.lang.Math.random()

If we check the [Math class source code](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java/?v=source), we can view this:

```
private static Random randomNumberGenerator;

private static synchronized void initRNG() {
    if (randomNumberGenerator == null)
        randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
}

public static double random() {
    if (randomNumberGenerator == null) initRNG();
    return randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble();
}
```

Math.random() is simply a shortcut to call Random Class. It is more simple and less complete than java.util.Random but it's enough in some cases.

### java.util.Random

The Random class implement a [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

LCG is a pretty simple formula for Pseudorandom Number Generation. java.util.Random is not trully random, it is totally deterministric. With the same initial condition (also called the seed), you've got the same result in the same order.

Use `java.util.Random` is good for the most use cases *(simulation, games, ...)* but is not good for cryptography because of his predictability, for this kind of use case prefer `java.security.SecureRandom`.

`java.util.Random` is thread safe but can have performance issues in multi-threaded context. If you work in a multi-threaded application, prefer `ThreadLocalRandom`.

### java.security.SecureRandom

The SecureRandom class extend `java.util.Random` class to implement a cryptographically strong random number generator based on an entropy source. SecureRandom is not deterministic.

SecureRandom have multiple implementation in function of your platform ([the complete implementation list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SecureRandomImp)).

`java.security.SecureRandom` is less fast than `java.util.Random` because of entropy source.

### java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom

The ThreadLocalRandom class is another implementation of [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) but this one isn't thread-safe but dedicated to a specific thread.

[This implementation is more fast than `java.util.Random` in multi-threaded context.](http://java-performance.info/java-util-random-java-util-concurrent-threadlocalrandom-multithreaded-environments/)

---

In your case, you could use `java.util.Collections.shuffle(list)` to shuffle your array with `java.util.Random` or with a specific Random Generator like `java.security.SecureRandom`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `java.util.Random` API

> An instance of this class is used to generate a stream of pseudorandom numbers. The class uses a 48-bit seed, which is modified using a linear congruential formula. (See Donald Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 3, Section 3.2.1.)

Algorithm class : *pseudorandom number generator* known as **PRNG**. You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

Note : `Math.random()` also uses `java.util.Random` instance  to generate the psuedo-random numbers internally

Comment: A `PRNG` is a class of algorithms; not an algorithm in it's own right.

Answer (score 1):

It uses the pseudo random number generation algorithms ie the numbers which are constantly fluctuating from throughout the system.

You may also find this interseting to read:- [Pseudo-Random vs. True Random](http://boallen.com/random-numbers.html)

Also check the **[Source for java.util.Random](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Random-source.html)**

Comment: I don't see how this answer adds value. The `java.util.Random` class may use system obtained values as a seed, but after that it uses a deterministic algorithm for generating further numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do what you are trying to do is

```
String[] words = ...
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(words));
```

You are right that generating a random double and then turning it into a small integer is not efficient.  Fortunately Random has a method for this.

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = words.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
     int sd = rand.nextInt(i+1); // random number between 0 and i inclusive

     String t = words[r];
     words[r] = words[i];
     words[i] = t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 methods to Shuffle an Array:

Approach 1: Shuffle elements in an array

Approach 2: Java Collection.shuffle() method

And the method you use is one standard way accomplishing  this.

There are 2 ways in java: [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and [java.lang.Math.random.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29)
java.lang.Math.random() uses java.util.Random.
It provides only doubles and has no seeding capability.